# Connection failed due to timeout when connecting Android with MongoDB

Tags: android, mongodb, android-studio

I am trying to connect my Android application to MongoDB and insert values to it. The application crashes by prompting the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.preyanshu.mongodblogin/com.example.preyanshu.mongodblogin.MainActivity}: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=10.100.17.139:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.100.17.139 (port 27017) after 20000ms}}]
```

This is the code which I am using to connect directly to the database:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button login, ViewBtn;
EditText u_name, pwd;
TextView showView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        showView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showView);
        ViewBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        u_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userName);
        pwd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("10.100.17.139",27017);

        MongoCredential credential;
        credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("sampleUser", "LoginSample", "password".toCharArray());

        MongoDatabase dbs = (MongoDatabase) mongoClient.getDatabase("LoginSample");

        MongoCollection<Document> coll = dbs.getCollection("LoginData");

        Document docs = new Document("name","Test").append("password","Test");

        coll.insertOne(docs);

    }
}
```

The error is prompted only if I try to insert the docs. When I comment the line-

```
coll.insertOne(docs);
```

the application runs absolutely fine.

It would be a great help if I get a solution for this.

Comment: Is your PC/Laptop and device in same network?

Comment: yes it is in same network

Comment: Is your firewall disabled?

Comment: I have disabled it and checked but it is still not working

Comment: Is mongod up and running? Can you `telnet 10.100.17.139 27017` from the PC ? Can you do the same from the mobile?

Comment: Mongod is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error clearly states that the database can not be found/connected. This is not a code error, if you are reading rather than inserting, still the same error will come. Its your andriod app, are you trying to connect through the phone ? Or through the development system? If its through the system, then try connecting to Mongo through mongo client or even mongo compass. Pretty sure that will also fail. Just network issue, either the machine is not available or the security groups have not exposed the port. Your dev-ops guy would be the best person to solve it : -) Good luck !

Edit, Quick look at your code and your URL pattern looks wrong, now I feel silly to  have typed all the network hullalala

```
 MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("10.100.17.139",27017);
```

IT does not follows the URL patter, the correct pattern will be :

```
"mongodb://10.100.17.139"
```

Or you need to wrap it as New server !